# Issue with python schedule library

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I'm trying to use the python schedule library to run a script every day at midnight on GMT-7. I'm assuming it's using GMT time, or system time, so I set it to run at 17:00 every day, but for some reason is starts straight away every time I run it. This is the code I am using.

```
schedule.every().day.at("17:00").do(getRegressionData(subredditList))
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Any ideea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently explicitly calling the `getRegressionData` function with the argument `subredditList` and pass the return value to `do`.

As per the [docs](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#schedule.Job.do), `do` accepts a function and optional positional and keyword arguments. It then calls the function for you at the desired time with the provided arguments.

Use `do(getRegressionData, subredditList)`.